# Plotly and Shiny: is it possible to get event data as list object?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, data-visualization, shiny-reactivity

**Question:** Using plotly and shiny, is it possible to extract a list of curveNumber, pointNumber, x and y all at once?

**Example (see code):** By clicking on each bar, `p` returns below. Is it possible to get a list of x-values, pointNumbers etc without clicking on the plot initially? I.e. x-object of c(4, 6, 8), pointNumber object c(0, 1, 2)

```
  curveNumber pointNumber x    y
1           0           2 8 15.1
  curveNumber pointNumber x        y
1           0           1 6 19.74286
```

**Sample code**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      mtcars %>%
            group_by(cyl) %>%
            summarise(m = mean(mpg)) %>%
            plot_ly(., x = ~cyl,
              y = ~m, source = "test_plot") %>%
            add_bars()
    })

    observe({
        p <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "test_plot")
        print(p)
    })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want. You can get `x` and `y` with `plotly_build`, see below. And `pointNumber` is just `0`, ..., `length(x)-1`.

```
p <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(m = mean(mpg)) %>%
  plot_ly(., x = ~cyl,
          y = ~m, source = "test_plot") %>%
  add_bars() 

pp <- plotly_build(p)
curves <- pp$x$data
curveNumber <- 0
dat <- curves[[curveNumber+1]]
as.vector(dat$x)
# [1] 4 6 8
as.vector(dat$y)
# [1] 26.66364 19.74286 15.10000
```